# How to implement user permission assignment module in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-permissions

i want to implement a module within Django template where admin user can assign model wise permissions to users/group. Attached is the image for your reference. please check and help

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created different groups and permissions using models and its working within admin. But not able to find how to do it within template

Comment: Django also provide this feature. ``/admin``  this url show this feature.Please check this @Discovery World

Comment: @RiyasAc I know this. but i wanted to implement this feature in template where any user with admin right would be able to manage uses permission without login to /admin panel